# ٌWhat should I do when I have an important question which didn't get enough attention

Tags: support, bounty

I have an important question that I'm very in need of discussing with some people. Unfortunately, someone makes it a minus one vote at the start. After that no one answer or even comment on the question [Non-i.i.d Empirical Risk Minimization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/790021/non-i-i-d-empirical-risk-minimization)
Thank you for your help

Comment: Once you have more reputation, you can add a bounty to the question.

Comment: I suppose you can find similar discussions here on meta. Have you tried searching for some reasonable keywords, for example [attention](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/search?q=attention) or [attention+question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/search?q=attention+question)? Have you looked at questions listed in the list of related questions on the right?

Comment: Is it maybe a better question for the statistics site?

Comment: @ Martin Sleziak, I'm relatively new to the site and I didn't know details of how voting, bounty and other things work. thank you. I looked at questions related to this question but I didn't find anything.

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson, I am not aware of any statistics site. Could you name some important statistics site? Thank you

Comment: Down at the bottom of this very page, I see a listing of sites in the stackexchange network. Under the heading "Science", I see "Cross Validated (stats)". I also see that you chose to post to MathOverflow, without mentioning the crosspost here or there. I hope that if you choose to post to Cross Validated, you will mention all your other posts there, and link to the Cross Validated post at m.se, MO, and meta.mse; also, I hope you will take advantage of the formatitng help you were given at m.se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Once you get sufficient reputation ($75$), you can start a bounty.](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) You can give a bounty by taking $50$ to $500$ points off of your reputation and providing it as a reward to the best answerer. [If you want to know more about bounties, click this sentence.](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)